# Is it okay to use "Box" component for everything?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, emotion, styled-system

I'm currently using emotion with styled-system plugin and documentation there is some example of Box component, which we can use to create some blocks of our layout, like :

```js
<Box width={1/2}>
  <Box mb={2}>
   box 1
  </Box>
  <Box mb={2}>
   box 2
  </Box>
</Box>
```

In some other examples I also saw Text component which accepts props like fontSize, fontFamily and so on.

What is the purpose to create Text component if we can achieve same result with Box? And it will more shorter :

```js
<Box width={100}>
  <Text fontSize={2}>text</Text>
</Box>

// vs 

<Box width={100} fontSize={2}>
  text
</Box>
```

Maybe it's because of some performance moments?

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the reasons for this is semantics (human readability). At a glance you will not be able to tell what things are if they are all "boxes". Everything can *inherit* from box, but should not just be a box if there are better options to choose from, like `Image` or `Flex`.

You also run the risk of having too many props such as `fontSize` for something that only controls layout. Better to have things separated on the basis on what they represent, regardless of if they share the same properties.

This model is what standard html uses, as

```
<Box>
   <Text>Hello world</Text>
</Box>
```

is very much like

```
<div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is probably wrong, but I kind of find it too cumbersome when I want to create a simple text with an 5px margin (for example) and for this I will still need to create a Box around it. and use something like <Box><Text></Text></Box>
or is this approach still more correct?

Comment: That was perhaps a bit of a contrived example. The div I showed would presumably have other children. You're right, that it's a bit odd to keep repeating this pattern for one offs. A `Text` can still inherit from `Box` (that's how I design things at least, all roads lead to Box). So you can just do `<Text m={2} width="100px">foo</Text>` as you see fit. Also remember to consider using the `as` keyword, so that your text can turn into p/H1/span etc etc. Overall your intuition is correct, as long as Text is a styled(Box). You'll still get the benefits of readability, while all the props from Box.